# How do I set my html input to ngSelected from an array property Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a set of projects in an object each projects come with this HTML section

```
<label class="checkbox-container">
  <input ng-click="addProcurementToPlan(project)" 
         ng-show="showCheckBox()" 
         class="checkbox" 
         type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

I want to ensure that if a property in my project is true then my HTML checkbox should show checked or selected.

When I inspect my HTML element when I click the checkbox I can't see the angularjs property that is making my tag look selected or checked for me to write a function for it.

Comment: Kindly ignore the ng-click="addProcurementToPlan(project)" ng-show="showCheckBox()"  I am usinng it for another part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-selected directive only works for `<select>` tags.

For input of type "checkbox", use the ng-checked directive instead.

```
<input ng-click="addProcurementToPlan(project)" 
     ng-show="showCheckBox()" 
     class="checkbox" 
     type="checkbox"
     ng-checked="property">
```

If $scope.property is true, then your box should be checked.